# generate random integers with a specific sum

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 5 fields, I want them all to have a generated number between 0 and 100. But, the sum of the 5 fields should be 100.

When I want to give a random number for one field I would do the following:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x= rnd.Next(1, 10);
```

But how should I do that for multiple fields that needs to have a sum of 100 together?

Comment: Do it for four fields, the subtract their sum from 100 to get the fifth?

Comment: @ChrisPickford - Suppose he were to choose the first four numbers with mean 20, and if the sum was still below zero, choose the last number as the difference. Wouldn't this mean that the last number had a different distribution from the first 4?

Comment: @AdamBrown Where in the question does it mention distribution? The only defined requirement is that the sum of the five numbers is 100.

Comment: @xxx2017 - do you need all the numbers to be expected to have the same size, or are you Ok with one of the numbers being on average as big as the other 4 put together?

Comment: @AdamBrown I dont want the numbers to be of the same size. They should be random.

Comment: I've run a [simple performance comparison](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XiCNPA) on the top three answers. For small values Milster's solution is the fastest although as you increase size of result set and/or target sum then the clear victor is Dmitry's.

Comment: You can't have 5 random numbers between 0 and 100 that all sum to 100. Then they aren't random. What if the first random number is 100? Are the other 4 numbers supposed to be 0? Assigning four 0s is no longer random. You need to spend some time thinking about what you actually want and whether they should be truly random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your first random number. After that you take the difference between the value of `num1` and 100 as the `max def of rnd`. But to guarantee that their sum is 100, you have to check at the last `num` if the sum of all `nums` is 100. If not the value of your last `num` is the difference that their sum and 100.

And to simply your code and get a clean strcuture, put that code in a loop and instead of single numbers work with an `int[5]` array.

---

```
private int[] CreateRandomNumbersWithSum()
{
    int[] nums = new int[5];
    int difference = 100;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = rnd.Next(0, difference);

        difference -= nums[i];
    }

    int sum = 0;

    foreach (var num in nums)
        sum += num;

    if (sum != 100)
    {
        nums[4] = 100 - sum;
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Your numbers won't have the same distribution - the OP's post implies that all the numbers should have the same expected value.

Comment: And how/why do you think that all numbers need to have the same value? OP never mentioned that. He says explicit that `I want them all to have a generated number between 0 and 100`.

Comment: the numbers per  should be different(random) but the total should always be 100.

Comment: Indeed, but when you're choosing 5 "random" values as opposed to 1, you would typically (in fact in almost all conceivable circumstances) what them all to be random with respect to each other.

Comment: @xxx2017 Thats what my solution does. It gives you 5 random numbers between 0 and 100 and the sum of all of them will be 100. I´ll write the complete example for you. Wait a second.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only thing I need to know: If i Call this method in the same class and I want ti have each generated number to be put in the following variables:
int one
int two
int three
int four
int five

How can I do that? I am not so familiar with returns that have multiple values.

Comment: @xxx2017 Since it works for you, please consider marking it as your accepted answer (clicking the gray check). This method returns an `array` and you can access the values of the array this way: `nums[0] = ...; nums[1] = ...;` and so on... . So instead if `int one, int two,...` can you use this `array` of `int` variables, the variables are just put in the array to give them a structure and make it easier to handle all of them at once. But in the end you could still assign the values of the `array nums[]` to your variables by: `int one = nums[1];` and so on... .

Comment: This should in no sense be the accepted answer. qwertyman has it at the moment.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following approach:

1. generate 4 random integers in [0, 100]
2. sort them, let's denote the sorted values as 0 ≤ x<sub>1</sub> ≤ x<sub>2</sub> ≤ x<sub>3</sub> ≤ x<sub>4</sub> ≤ 100
3. use the following 5 values as the random numbers with sum 100:

   - N<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>1</sub>
   - N<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>
   - N<sub>3</sub> = x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>
   - N<sub>4</sub> = x<sub>4</sub> - x<sub>3</sub>
   - N<sub>5</sub> = 100 - x<sub>4</sub>

---

It basically corresponds to randomly choosing 4 sectioning points on the [0, 100] interval, and using the lengths of the 5 resulting intervals as the random numbers:

[image]

```
const int k = 5;
const int sum = 100;

Random rnd = new Random();
int[] x = new int[k + 1];

// the endpoints of the interval
x[0] = 0;
x[k] = sum;

// generate the k - 1 random sectioning points
for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
    x[i] = rnd.Next(0, sum + 1);
}

// sort the sectioning points
Array.Sort(x);

// obtain the k numbers with sum s
int[] N = new int[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    N[i] = x[i + 1] - x[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code? I suspect that this approach will not produce a random distribution of numbers.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know C#, but why do you suspect that? Under the above procedure, every sectioning of the [0, 100] interval is equiprobable, and the sectioning of this interval is directly related to obtaining a set of numbers with sum 100. Maybe the picture that I added is not very appropriate (it might suggest that partitions in intervals of roughly the same length are more likely, but this is not the case).

Comment: @Enigmativity - my appropriation of this approach can be seen in the following fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XiCNPA

Comment: @Enigmativity I also added an implementation to this answer.

Comment: @qwertyman - I was mistaken. This is an awesome approach. The only remaining issue I see is that `rnd.Next(0, 100)` produces numbers between `0` and `99`, not `100`.

Answer (score 5):

In order to make your distribution uniform, you could try the following aproach:

1. Generate some random numbers.
2. Normalize them.
3. Correct the last field to get exactly the expected sum, if needed.

The code:

```
const int ExpectedSum = 100;

Random rnd = new Random();
int[] fields = new int[5];

// Generate 4 random values and get their sum
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length - 1; i++)
{
    fields[i] = rnd.Next(ExpectedSum);
    sum += fields[i];
}

// Adjust the sum as if there were 5 random values
int actualSum = sum * fields.Length / (fields.Length - 1);

// Normalize 4 random values and get their sum
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length - 1; i++)
{
    fields[i] = fields[i] * ExpectedSum / actualSum;
    sum += fields[i];
}

// Set the last value
fields[fields.Length - 1] = ExpectedSum - sum;
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5yXwOP

Answer (score 3):

To achieve a truly random distribution, with every element having the chance to be 100 with a total sum of 100, you can use the following solution:

```
public static int[] GetRandomDistribution(int sum, int amountOfNumbers)
{

    int[] numbers = new int[amountOfNumbers];
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++)
    {
      numbers[random.Next(0, amountOfNumbers)]++;
    }
    return numbers;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = GetRandomDistribution(100, 5);
}
```

It increases a random number by one until the sum is reached. This should fulfill all your criterias.

After thinking about it, I prefer the following solution, because it's less likely to generate an equal distribution:

```
public static int[] GetRandomDistribution2(int sum, int amountOfNumbers)
{

    int[] numbers = new int[amountOfNumbers];

    var random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++)
    {
      numbers[i] = random.Next(sum);
    }


    var compeleteSum = numbers.Sum();

    // Scale the numbers down to 0 -> sum
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++)
    {
      numbers[i] = (int)(((double)numbers[i] / compeleteSum) * sum);
    }

    // Due to rounding the number will most likely be below sum
    var resultSum = numbers.Sum();

    // Add +1 until we reach "sum"
    for (int i = 0; i < sum - resultSum; i++)
    {
      numbers[random.Next(0, amountOfNumbers)]++;
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Note, you could do it with a logarithmic approach to the sum, so that the first five numbers would be chosen in [0, 20], then next five in [0, remaining/5] etc...

Comment: @AdamBrown why is it uniform? if _e.g._ we were looking for only two numbers, this approach would produce a combination like [50, 50] much more often than one like [100, 0].

Comment: This solutions provides even more pseudo random numbers than `Random()` already creates.  Does not give a huge range difference of number's values in most cases.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that all the numbers are chosen from the same distribution - it actually tends towards a Normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For Example.

```
int sum=100;
int i = 5;
Random rnd = new Random();
while (true)
{
    int cur;                
    --i;
    if (i == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(sum + " ");
        break;
    } else 
        cur=rnd.Next(1, sum);
    sum -= cur;        
    Console.WriteLine(cur + " ");                
}
```

Live Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ltIK40

or

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x= rnd.Next(1, 10);    
int y= rnd.Next(x,x+10);
int y2=rnd.Next(y,y+10);
int y3=rnd.Next(y2,y2+10);
int y4=100-(x+y+y2+y3);
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => rnd.Next(0, 101)).ToArray().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
numbers = numbers.Zip(numbers.Skip(1), (n0, n1) => n1 - n0).ToArray();
numbers = numbers.Concat(new[] { 100 - numbers.Sum() }).ToArray();
```

This is as uniform as I think is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very simple solution:

```
public void GenerateRandNr(int total)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var nr1 = rnd.Next(0, total);
        var nr2 = rnd.Next(0, total - nr1);
        var nr3 = rnd.Next(0, total - nr1 - nr2);
        var nr4 = rnd.Next(0, total - nr1 - nr2 - nr3);
        var nr5 = total - nr1 - nr2 - nr3 - nr4;
    }
```

EDIT:
Just tested it, works fine for me: [image]

Comment: The numbers won't have the same distribution.

Comment: @AdamBrown you cant have the same distribution! How could the sum be 100 if every nr could be between 0 and 100?

Comment: So the OP never said they can be between 0 and 100, although my answer would still deliver the same distribution if they were...

Comment: @AdamBrown value per var cannot be lower than 0 and not higher than 100 and all variables together should have a sum of 100.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that it's not the numbers that need to be random so much as the distribution needs to be random. The randomness of the numbers will be a side effect of their random distribution.

So you would start with five random numbers in a given range. The exact range doesn't matter as long as the range is the same for all five, although a broader range allows for more variation. I'd use Random.NextDouble() which returns random numbers between 0 and 1.

Each of those individual numbers divided by the sum of those numbers represents a distribution.

For example, say your random numbers are .4, .7, .2, .5, .2. (Using fewer digits for simplicity.)

The total of those numbers is 2. So now the distributions are each of those numbers divided by the total.

```
.4 / 2 = .20
.7 / 2 = .35
.2 / 2 = .10
.5 / 2 = .25
.2 / 2 = .10
```

You'll notice that those distributions will equal 100% or really close to it if there are a lot more decimal places.

The output is going to be each of those distributions times the target number, in this case, 100. In other words, each of those numbers represents a piece of 100.

So multiplying each of those distributions times the target, we get 20, 35, 10, 25, and 100, which add up to 100.

The trouble is that because of rounding your numbers won't always perfectly add up to 100. To fix that you might add one to the smallest number if the sum is less than 100, or subtract one from the largest number of the the sum is greater than 100. Or you could choose to add or subtract on one of the numbers at random.

Here's a class to create the distributions. (I'm just playing around so I haven't exactly optimized this to death.)

```
public class RandomlyDistributesNumbersTotallingTarget
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetTheNumbers(int howManyNumbers, int targetTotal)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var distributions = new List<double>();
        for (var addDistributions = 0; addDistributions < howManyNumbers; addDistributions++)
        {
            distributions.Add(random.NextDouble());
        }
        var sumOfDistributions = distributions.Sum();
        var output = distributions.Select(
            distribution => 
                (int)Math.Round(distribution / sumOfDistributions * targetTotal, 0)).ToList();
        RoundUpOutput(output, targetTotal);
        return output;
    }

    private void RoundUpOutput(List<int> output, int targetTotal)
    {
        var difference = targetTotal - output.Sum();
        if (difference !=0)
        {
            var indexToAdjust =
                difference > 0 ? output.IndexOf(output.Min()) : output.IndexOf(output.Max());
            output[indexToAdjust]+= difference;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a not-perfectly-scientific unit test that tests it many times over and ensures that the results always total 100.

```
[TestMethod]
public void OutputTotalsTarget()
{
    var subject = new RandomlyDistributesNumbersTotallingTarget();
    for (var x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
    {
        var output = subject.GetTheNumbers(5, 100);
        Assert.AreEqual(100, output.Sum());
    }
}
```

Some sample outputs:

5, 30, 27, 7, 31
15, 7, 26, 27, 25
10, 11, 23, 2, 54

The numbers are always going to average to 20, so while 96, 1, 1, 1 is a hypothetical possibility they're going to tend to hover closer to 20.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Having been burned by my previous attempt at this seemingly trivial problem, I decided to have another go. Why not normalise all the numbers after generation? This guarantees randomness, and avoids O(n log n) performance from a sort. It also has the advantage that even with my basic maths, I can work out that the numbers are uniformly distributed.

```
public static int[] UniformNormalization(this Random r, int valueCount, int valueSum)
{
    var ret = new int[valueCount];
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++)
    {
        var next = r.Next(0, valueSum);
        ret[i] = next;
        sum += next;
    }

    var actualSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++)
    {
        actualSum += ret[i] = (int)((ret[i] * valueSum) / sum);
    }

    //Fix integer rounding errors.
    if (valueSum > actualSum)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < valueSum - actualSum; i++)
        {
            ret[r.Next(0, valueCount)]++;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This should also be one of the fastest solutions.

Comment: @ChrisPickford - how does this compare?